# How to display / render data from fetched api with the help of async await

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have one function in which I get data from the API and parsing it to json.

In the second function, I try to insert data into a DOM element.

Where is the problem, please, and how do we render this data correctly?

Firt function:

```
// GET PUBLIC IP
const getIp = async () => {

    const reqIp = await fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=xxx")
    return reqIp.json()

}
```

Second function:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    const dataIp = await getIp()
    let ipAdress = document.querySelectorAll('.ip p')
    ipAdress.innerHTML = dataIp.ip
})

getIp()
```

DOM:

```
<div class="ip">
  <h5>Your IP Adress:</h5>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

The token is OK, the data is displayed correctly in the console.

Comment: Try `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`. `querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist so you can't use `innerHTML`. `querySelector` returns _one_ node.

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a NodeList

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, too much redbull and too little sleep.

Thank you very much guys.

As they wrote in the comments, the problem was in the selector.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    const dataIp = await getIp()
    let ipAdress = document.querySelector('.ip p')
    ipAdress.innerHTML = dataIp.ip
})

getIp()
```

This is how it works without problems